# Manter tamanho da imagem para impressão em CSS

Tags: css3, div, impressora

Pessoal como eu faço para gerar uma imagem que ficara de background em uma div com um texto sobrepondo ela e na hora que eu imprimir ela manter o seu tamanho. Tipo eu tenho uma imagem gerada no Photoshop com as seguintes dimensões: 1024px por 749px com 200 dpis isto daria 13x9,5 cms real. So que quando coloco ela no html e peço para imprimir ela fica com a largura total da pagina 20cms. Estou usando o seguinte CSS para esta div:

```
#div{
     width: 1024px;
     height: 749px;
     background: url(cartao.jpg) no-repeat !important;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```